# Update specific row and column of dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to store user input into a pre-existing dataframe in shiny.

In this simplified example I have a dataframe with a column labelled 'colour' and I want radio choice buttons to be able to assign values to each row in the dataframe, starting with row 1, then row 2 then row 3 etc. But it seems the dataframe always resets to the original value.  What am I misunderstanding about shiny here?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
dataframe <- tibble(row_id = c(1,2,3),
                    colour = c("","",""))
ui <- fluidPage(
    radioButtons("colour",
                 "Pick a colour:", 
                 choices = c("blue","green","red")),
actionButton("next_button", "Pick the next colour"),
DTOutput("dataframe")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
vals <- reactiveValues(active_row = 1)
    observeEvent(input$next_button,{ 
            dataframe[vals$active_row, "colour"]  = input$colour
            # view(dataframe)
            # print(vals$active_row)
            vals$active_row = vals$active_row + 1
            output$dataframe <- renderDataTable(dataframe)
    })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store your data also in `reactiveValues`. In addition, you can move your `output` outside of your `observeEvent`. This `server` function should work based on your description.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  vals <- reactiveValues(active_row = 1, data = dataframe)
  observeEvent(input$next_button,{ 
    vals$data[vals$active_row, "colour"]  = input$colour
    vals$active_row = vals$active_row + 1
  })
  output$dataframe <- renderDataTable(vals$data)
}
```